# select nth child from 2 levels up

Tags: html, css

I have an html structure like this:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so we have parent -> row -> button, 1 parent, 2 rows, each row has 2-4 buttons. is there a css selector I can use (like nth-child) but that treats all buttons as siblings (even if they're in different rows)? Something like:

```
.parent .child:nth-child(randomNum) {

}
```

where randomNum is a number between 1 and numOfTotalButtons.length

Comment: what do you want? some more explaination

Comment: @RobinHood i think the question is clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that it is not possible using only CSS. You can archive this using jQuery or pure Javascript :

```js
//jQuery
$(".button").eq(0).css("color", "red");
$(".button").eq(1).css("color", "green");
//pure javascript
document.querySelectorAll(".button")[2].style.color = "blue";
document.querySelectorAll(".button")[3].style.color = "pink";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the sibling selector `~`.

```css
.row ~ .row > .button {
  color: hotpink;
}

.row ~ .row ~ .row > .button {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is helpful but i was specifically looking for (as my question title says) `from 2 levels up`

Answer (score 1):

> *"is there a css selector I can use (like nth-child) but that treats all buttons as siblings (even if they're in different rows)?"*

Yeah, class selector. Is there any other requirements and/or circumstances that you need to address other than that?

```css
.button {
  outline: red 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
    <div class='button'>
      button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```